# Django: How to access fields in chained querysets using for loop?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using `django v1.8`

I have to models in `models.py`:

```
class Demographic:
    patient_id = models.IntegerField(unique= True ,primary_key=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class MyTest:
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
    date_vaccination =  models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Regarding the `date_vaccination` and the `age` of the patient I want to find **for all the patients who were vaccinated** their age when they vaccinated.

And this result I want to show it to chart using `chartit` module.

In `views.py` I have:

```
total_patients = Demographic.objects.filter(mytest__date_vaccination__isnull = False)
total_patients_vac = MyTest.objects.filter(date_vaccination__isnull = False)

result_list = list(chain(total_patients, total_patients_vac))
```

I'm using chain to add these `querysets` to list. Then for each patient I want to compute their age when they were vaccinated to show it in chart.

When I'm trying to iterate the chained list I get the error `'MyTest' object has no attribute 'age'`

```
for e in result_list:
        print e.age
```

I want to have this:

```
x = e.age - e.date_vaccination
```

in the for loop and add the result to a new list.

Comment: I don't even know what are you trying to do with `e.Demographic.age`.

Comment: @ShangWang I concatenate two querysets. Clinical_data_two has foreign key to Demographic. I want to access a specific field from Demographic and one from  Clinical_data_two for each patient. Both fields are datetime.

Comment: Shang, can you explain better what do you want? It's a little bit confuse.

Comment: @Rubico I updated my question.

Comment: @ShangWang I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zinon,

as I could understand what you want. You want to get all age of patients that were vacinated.

I would not use this chain method, as the Django ORM is smart enough to get the data for you from the MyTest class.

```
vaccines = MyTest.objects.filter(date_vaccination__isnull = False)
for vaccine in vaccines:
    age = vaccine.patient.age
    vaccine_date = vaccine.date_vaccination
```

This happens because when you declare the `models.ForeignKey` on a Django model you are not just putting a number there (on the Database you are), you can have the access to the real `Demographic` object just doing `vaccine.patient`

```
class MyTest:
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
    date_vaccination =  models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

By the way, I don't know your real needs, but would not save the age of a patient, since this can be calculated using the patient birthday. I would just save his birthday and calculate his/her age according to the vaccine date.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's is the proper solution!